# TFS Build Agent Use Multiple Configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, build-agent

I'm trying to use the TFS Build Agent to replace my old Build.bat file that builds all of my projects.  I have C# and C++ projects that need to be compiled.  All of the C# projects have the configuration Release|Any CPU and all of the C++ projects have the Release|Win32 configuration.  I've created a MSBuild project that includes all of my projects.  How do I specify that the C++ projects should use the Release|Win32 configuration and the C# projects should use the Release|Any CPU configuration.
thanks
John.

Answer (score 0):

Are your projects contained in a single solution? If so, you can create a solution configuration that maps the appropriate project-level configurations for each project.

Comment: no, each project is in a seperate solution.  I have 155 projects that need to be built, so I would prefer to not to put them all into 1 solution.

Comment: In the Process section of the Build Definition, select all of the projects (yikes) as items to build and their appropriate Configuration.  It is important to remember that Solutions AND projects have configurations.  Solution Configurations are meta only.  That is, in the Solution configuration you choose which projects are build and what configuration to build.  So, AppA.SLN could have Release/ANYCPU, but build ProjA.csproj Debug|x86 and ProjB.csproj Release|ANYCPU.  The term "Configuration" is pretty overloaded in these scenarios.

Comment: Where is the Process section of the Build Definition?